# Every time I click on a item its getting added to cart.I need to delete previously added items before adding new `item` in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

My question may be duplicate.But those are using magento.

I need help to delete previously added items in cart before adding the new item.

What exactly happening now is each time i click on a `item` ,it's adding number of items.But what I actually need is only newest item to be added in cart.
Here is my code.

**service.js**

```
.factory('CartService', [function () {
var svc = {};
svc.saveCart = function(cart){
window.localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
};
svc.loadCart = function(){
var cart = window.localStorage.getItem('cart');
if(!cart){
return { products : [ ] }
}
return JSON.parse(cart);
};
svc.resetCart = function(){
var cart =  { products : [ ] };
svc.saveCart(cart);
return cart;
};

svc.getTotal = function(cart){
var out = 0;
if(!cart || !cart.products || !angular.isArray(cart.products)){
return out;
}
for(var i=0; i < cart.products.length; i++){
out += cart.products[i].price;
}
return out;
}
return svc;
}])
```

**controller.js**

```
.controller('FoodCtrl', function($scope,$state,mySharedService,     $ionicActionSheet, BackendService, CartService) {

$scope.cart = CartService.loadCart();

$scope.doRefresh = function(){
  BackendService.getFood()
  .success(function(newItems) {
    $scope.products = newItems;
  })
  .finally(function() {
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
  });
  };

  var addProductToCart = function(product){
  $scope.cart.products.push(product);
  CartService.saveCart($scope.cart);
  };

  $scope.addProduct = function(product){
  $ionicActionSheet.show({
   buttons: [
     { text: '<b>Add to produce</b>' }
   ],
   titleText: 'add to cart ' + product.itemName,
   cancelText: 'Cancel',
   cancel: function() {
      // add cancel code if needed ..
   },
   buttonClicked: function(index) {
     if(index == 0){
       addProductToCart(product);
       return true;
     }
     return true;
     }
    });
    };
```

Any response be greatly helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: so everytime you add product to a cart you want to remove previous products ?

Comment: yes i need to remove previous products

Comment: Only the current added item should be available in cart

Comment: in that case check if array is empty or not if not just empty it, like `if (products.length !== 0) { products = []; products.push(product);} else {products.push(product);}`

Comment: yes i have checked, `product.length` is undefined.But in product values are there

Comment: that was example, in your case I think array name will be `$scope.cart.products` this is where you are pushing the product right ?

Comment: yes..$scope.cart.products

Comment: then in that code snippet instead of products use `$scope.cart.products`

Comment: @warl0ck.. Its working thank you

Comment: I have posted it as answer as well, please accept, if it helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do so first check if array is empty or not if not just empty it

Like:

```
if ($scope.cart.products.length !== 0) { 
    $scope.cart.products= []; 
    $scope.cart.products.push(product);
} else {
    $scope.cart.products.push(product);
}
```